# ASP.NET Event PreInit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am developing a web application with asp.net,
in PreInit event, when I just put a message it work

```
If IsPostBack Then
Dim eTarget As String = Request.Params("__EVENTTARGET").ToString()
If (eTarget = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Buttonpub") Then
MsgBox("it's work")
End If
End If
```

And when i put code inside just don't enter in the "if"

```
If IsPostBack Then
Dim eTarget As String = Request.Params("__EVENTTARGET").ToString()
If (eTarget = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Buttonpub") Then
da.Fill(ds, "connexion")
dr = ds.Tables("connexion").NewRow()
dr("num_mbr") = Session("id")
dr("date_pub") = DateTime.Now
dr("type_pub") = "texte"
dr("contenu") = TextBox1.Text
ds.Tables("connexion").Rows.Add(dr)
da.Update(ds, "connexion")
TextBox1.Text = ""
MsgBox("don't work")
End If
End If
```

Thks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using the PreInit event?  In this event, none of the controls on the page have been initialized yet, so you don't have access to them.  Try doing this in the PreLoad event instead, keeping the: If IsPostBack Then... End If

You may find this article helpful. It explains the life cycle of a page and when you should use each event.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx